# Library installation with yocto recipe

Tags: linux, filesystems, yocto, recipe, cortex-a

have a bit of a problem creating a recipe for yocto. More specifically i have to install a library from git that normally installs like this:

```
./bootstrap
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc
make
sudo make install
```

My question is how can I add this to the recipe functions do_configure, do_compile, do_install. Haven't found much information or examples online.

Update 1:

This is the library that i want to integrate into yocto
https://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci

Comment: I assume that bootstrap is a shell-script, what does it do? Does it call out to  autotools? Could you show us that script? Apart from that step, it looks like a regular, possibly autotools based, recipe.

Comment: @Anders i've updated the post with the link to the lib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a regular autotools based library. The main issues, that someone ought to fix, are to make the build create versioned libraries and to add a `LICENSE` or `COPYING` file.

However, a quick recipe could look like:

```
SUMMARY = "Linux NFC stack for NCI based NXP NFC Controllers"
HOMEPAGE = ""
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://src/include/linux_nfc_api.h;endline=17;md5=42fdb99b3ff2c12f594b22a774cb7308"
SECTION = "libs"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci.git"
SRCREV = "118ea118cecda55c1b6a87d151a77b04515687df"
PV = "2.0+git${SRCPV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit autotools

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libnfc_nci_linux-1.so"
# Make sure it isn’t in the dev package’s files list
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = "${libdir}/libnfc_nci_linux.so"
```

A versioned library would allow us to remove the last three lines.

Comment: ok thanks but could you explain a bit to me how ./bootstrap
and ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc are working? when are they called?

make and make install i know that they are run by inheriting the autotools

Comment: `./boostrap` are never called, but if you look at that script, is basically just the standard calls to autotools. `./configure`  (and autotools) are called in the `do_configure` step, when running bitbake. Check `autotools.bbclass`.

Comment: i have the same issue and my library is at https://github.com/dailab/libsml i have no clue where to start. If i want to make a recipe. I have a setup where i add packages in the local.conf  but no idea how can i make my own